# Spring MVC not populating model attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to populate the object using model attribute. It's returning `null` from JSP to controller.

```
<form:form method="post" action="addProduct" modelAttribute="product">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="productName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Parent Product Id:</td>
            <td><form:input path="parentId"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category Id:</td>
            <td><form:input path="categoryId"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="AddProduct"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

---

```
@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@RequestMapping(value = "addProduct", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView productForm(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product){
    return new ModelAndView("addProduct"));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView insertProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product){
    System.out.println(product.getProductName() + " : " + product.getParentId() + " : " + product.getCategoryId());
    productService.insert(product);
    return new ModelAndView("success");
}
```

While getting the values back in controller using `modelAttribute` it's coming as `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Also there is one more thing I am doing same thing in my `Catergory class`, which is working perfectly fine.

Not able to understand what's wrong in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to my problem.

In my pojo class I had given different Name for the setter due to which it was unable to run.

Ex:
In my JSP i was giving

```
<form:input path="productName"/>
```

Where my path name is "productName" and in my POJO class i gave the same name for the variable but my setter name was different.

So in order to set the attribute value Spring will look for the setter with name of `set + attributeName()`.

Where in this above case it will be `set + productName()`

And my mistake was my setter had the name `setName()`.

Hope this helps the newbies of Spring like me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are actually adding a model to your ModelAndView.

This would pass a new Product object to your form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addProduct", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView productForm(){
    return new ModelAndView("addProduct", "product", new Product());
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried solution provided by u but still its not working, No ideas why its not working till it prints null on sysout line. But i m doing same in my other class its working fine.

Comment: I assume you entered data into the form before it was submitted?  And your Product class has a no arg constructor defined?

Comment: Hi, I have the both default and args constructor defined in my Product class still its not working...